# How to fix blury Docky Icons?

Tags: 11.10, icons, docky

I've looked everywhere online, and I cannot find an answer to this... My Docky Icons are blurry.  I currently have the Faenza icons enabled on Ubuntu 11.10, and they look great everywhere else on my system.  But my icons on docky are blurry.  I have removed them all and replaced them.  I have closed docky, updated docky, restarted my system; but they are still blurry.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to post your fix as an answer to your question and accept it. Please do that :)

Answer (score 3):

I figured out my own question, but since I had trouble finding an answer, I thought I should post my fix.

So it seems that when adjusting your Zoom and Icon size, you need to make sure that your Icon size has a lower value than the Zoom percentage. (Icon size needs to be at least 50% or lower than your current Zoom percentage).

I had to play with this a little bit, and you may as well. But hopefully this will save someone the agony I've been having.